# Relocate without relocate in subversion?

Tags: svn, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I need to switch the base URL of my working copy in subversion.

According to the manual for 1.7 I should be able to use svn relocate.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html

However, on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 I have version 1.6 which doesn't appear to have the relocate command.

Is there a way to accomplish this in subversion 1.6 or by some other method?

Comment: Subversion is *open source*. Download the 1.7 release and compile it yourself.

Comment: Sounds all very good but I don't want to break the package management.

Comment: Just discovered switch --relocate.  Looks to be what I want.

Comment: You lifesaver, you...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for.  It's just a matter of running

```
svn switch --relocate OLD_URL NEW_URL
```

It looks like on subversion 1.7 you can use the new syntax:

```
svn relocate NEW_URL
```

Comment: Also note that you must include not only the domain name but the correct scheme in your URL. Check your .svn/entries file to see what's being used.