# svn relocate not showing in svn help list what does it mean?

Tags: linux, git, svn

When i type `svn help` it shows the list of commands but `svn relocate` is not there in that list .
what does it mean ?
svn version is 1.6.11
   `ropdel (pdel, pd)
   propedit (pedit, pe)
   propget (pget, pg)
   proplist (plist, pl)
   propset (pset, ps)
   resolve
   resolved
   revert
   status (stat, st)
   switch (sw)
   unlock`

Comment: Don't use Subversion 1.6 or 1.7. There is no reason to use an outdated version (very outdated, actually). Use Subversion 1.9.

Comment: thanks so much for your valuable time and answer

Answer (score 2):

It simply means `svn relocate` is not available in svn 1.6.

You can find its documentation at [`1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html)

As mentioned in "[Relocate without relocate in subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14187740/6309)", in 1.6, that was:

```
svn switch --relocate OLD_URL NEW_URL
```

As opposed to 1.7:

```
svn relocate NEW_URL
```